# How can I remove all performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, exc-bad-access

I ran in to a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` when deallocating an object that has few `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay` where the selector methods is calling another object and I am releasing the object.

Somewhere in my class I am calling:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(callObject1Function) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];
```

and in my class I have:

```
- (void)callObject1Function{
    [object1 function1]  // Here I am getting "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [object1 release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

I just don't understand I thought when you `dealloc` it the object, everything associated with the object should be removed or canceled, even the `performSelector` with delay!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use `NSObject`'s:

```
-cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:selector:object:
```

to cancel any pending perform selectors.

Comment: Also just NSObject's +cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget: if you want to eliminate all selector and object perform requests to that target without specifying selectors and objects

Comment: You should cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget with the same target, the same selector and the *same* object. If the object is different, you didn't cancel anything. Important.

Answer (score 24):

I have used following code in my all apps and it's working.

```
[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(MethodName) object:nil];
```

Thanks,
Hemang.